# Why does my user territory assignment show inactive in UI, but still show Active in the backend via SOQL?

Tags: soql, territory-management, territory

We have Apex code that depends on the `UserTerritory2Association.IsActive` flag. For some reason, one of our user territory assignment is inactivate ('IsActve = false') but on the backend, the field is `true`.

[image]

A few questions:

1. How does one actually set this `InActive` checkbox? There doesn't appear to be a way to do this in the UI.
2. How can the checkbox be `false` in the UI but `true` when we run SOQL on that record?

We thought it may be due do the assigned user record being inactive, but when we deactivated the other assigned user, it completely remove him from the territory.